# Strange Inno Setup behavior with networked / shared resources

Tags: windows-7, network-programming, 64-bit, inno-setup

I have a puzzling situation with the Inno Setup FileExists function.

Here's the situation. I have three networked computers with like WORKGROUP names. 
1) Windows 7 32-bit
2) Windows 7 64-bit 
3) Window XP Service Pack 3

1) and 3) have been setup as servers with read-write shares, ex. ShareExe and ShareData

The problematic Inno Setup creates shortcuts to the executable in the ShareExe folder. It asks the user for the ComputerName of the server and then uses FileExists to verify correct input.

Running this setup on the XP (3) machine and specifying 1)'s computername works just fine, however when running the setup on the Win7 64-bit PC and specifying the same ComputerName as with XP, causes the FileExtsts test to fail.

Strangely, I can go to Network Places and open the ShareExe folder and successfully run the executable. My question is, "why does Inno FileExists fail only on the Win 7 64-bit machine?" I cannot find anything in the reference materials that suggest any version differences with FileExists. (I also tried FileSearch with the same results).

TIA

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 (and Vista) with UAC enabled, by default network credentials and drive mappings are not shared between admin and non-admin contexts, even for the same user.

By default, Inno elevates to admin permissions (via `PrivilegesRequired=admin`), since most installations must (and should) be performed per-machine by an admin user.  However this means that any credentials prompted for or saved by Explorer when browsing for the desktop are not available to it.

When files are accessed directly by APIs (as with FileExists), Windows will typically try to silently connect to the server using the same username/password as was used to log into the PC; if this fails then it just reports an error since it has no way to prompt for alternate credentials at that point.  So if you can ensure that the login details on both PCs are the same, then it should work.  (You usually get this for free on computers connected to a domain, but not a workgroup.)

If that isn't possible, then something else you could try would be to force the access via a shell dialog -- if the FileExists fails, then use `GetOpenFileName` to prompt the user to find a specific file in that folder, using the same initial path.  I haven't tested this, but I think this should result in Windows displaying a credential prompt and then you should be ok after that.

(If this is for an internal app, then another option is to disable the separation of credentials [via a security policy setting] or UAC entirely, though the latter isn't really a good idea.  Of course this isn't tolerable for a general-release app, and it's cleaner if you solve it one of the other ways anyway.)

Comment: Thank you for this thoughtful answer. Since this application is for general availability and the users are lay people, I was hoping that your GetOpenFileName suggestion would be a good solution. Unfortunately, the browse folder dialog does not accept the default folder parameter (\\{computername}\...) so the user must locate the shared root folder and navigate to the executable, which I think would baffle most of our target users. Is there a way of just verifying the server's computer name? (the user is prompted to enter it).

Comment: You need to use the file browser, not the folder browser.  Regarding the specific path, I was assuming that since you were only prompting for the computer name then you already knew the share name and path to at least one interesting file.  If that's not the case, then there are other ways to verify a computer name but you really should pick something similar to how your app is going to use it -- eg. if your app connects to it as a database server then do the same to validate it.  If your app opens a socket to a specific port then do the same.  Etc.